# Allow rollback when reviewing

Tags: feature-request, review, rollbacks

I've just come across a post in Low Quality Posts queue where OP has edited the body of the question to something like "Thanks, all, the issue is resolved." This certainly should be rolled back rather than deleted (or edited which is impossible without knowing the original content). However, it is not possible to do through Edit button and the only way is to get to the edit history which leads off the Review interface (And the only way out is Return to Question).

I believe this scenario should be handled within the Review Queue interface (having there a review panel with "cancel" and "Save Rollback" (like currently implemented for edits) or something along the lines).

Comment: Do you have a link to the post?

Comment: I can't see this occurring often enough to be worth the effort, but maybe some stats can change my mind

Comment: @jmort253 It is not in my review history because of this, I can't find it...

Comment: No worries, just things like that do give these requests context. I did vote up, but I suspect the answer is that the SE team wants to keep the reviews focused on the task for that particular review queue.

Comment: [This is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19888396/254830), I believe. You can find it in [your profile -> activity -> revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1564449/sashkello?tab=activity).